# How to route .html and .js files as PHP on Nginx FastCGI server?

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

For web servers using PHP as apache module:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

For web servers running PHP as CGI:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

I have an Nginx server and I want to run .js files and and .htm files as PHP, so I will have full PHP code inside them. Anyone know how to configure the Nginx to do this?

Comment: Are you sure this is a wise idea? It means that for every request for a HTML or JS file, the PHP interpreter will be started. It might be more resource saving to use URL rewriting for this

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning for wanting to do this? (It is a possible security risk and drag on the server).

Comment: @ikano it's a performance problem but I can't see how it is a security risk, can you elaborate? (Edit: Ah, I suppose you mean that code may get executed in arbitrary uploaded files)

Comment: Exactly, code execution in uploaded files :-)

Comment: I will serve it on a subdomain. Basically I am creating an ad server for a client. And they want to serve ad codes to their sites. So http://ad.nginx.com/serve.js?client=2343&zone=2&banner=22 example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example for .htm, .html files

```
  location ~ \.htm$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.htm;
            include        fastcgi.conf;
  }
```

Example for .js files

```
location ~ \.js$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

just change the extension and port settings if needed

Comment: Can it be limited to subdomains. Only .JS files I want to do this in a select folder area.

Comment: hmmm, getting a 502 now on all my js files.

Answer (score 22):

Passing to fastcgi didn't work for me. After a few hours of searching, I have found solution here:
http://ffct.cc/solving-nginx-php-fpm-access-denied-issue/

**In short:**

since PHP versions > 5.3.8, to make it works, you should add directive to your php-fpm.conf:

```
security.limit_extensions = .php .html .js
```

The recognition sign is "Access denied." (notice that it's different from HTTP error 403) when accesssing `.html` or `.js` file.

Answer (score 12):

**Simple; just change**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        root           html;
       fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

**to**

```
location ~ \.(php|html|htm)$ {
        root           html;
       fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: location ~ \.php|\.html|\.htm$ {  ... would also work.

Comment: Another +1 for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

Replying to this thread many years later, I spent three hours trying to solve this issue, I had all the right settings in my location block (`php|html|htm`) and in PHP-FPM (`security.limit_extensions`), my problem was that **I already had the .html extension in a previous location** which was used for some static files, so if anyone else is having issues despite using the right settings, please make sure that you're not making the same dumb mistake I did :)

Comment: Wow! Such a novice mistake to make and we all make these. Great find though! That would have been really painful and tiresome to NOT miss. Interestingly enough you did not just try a PHP and HTML file to see if it worked regardless :)

Answer (score 0):

Tom's answer with the link:

http://ffct.cc/solving-nginx-php-fpm-access-denied-issue/

was really helpful. However, I was using php with php-fpm installed on mac os yosemite w/ homebrew. Changes to the php-fpm.conf file did not take effect until I added the following to my .bash_profile:

```
 # for homebrew php55
 export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

For details see:

```
brew info php55
```

Answer (score 0):

In macOS 11.5 with PHP 8.0, when I browse http://localhost/index.html, it ends with `403` Forbidden

I had to change file `/usr/local/etc/php/8.0/php-fpm.d/www.conf` to set

```
security.limit_extensions = .php .html
```

PHP code blocks in my .html files are properly executed, following is my server block in nginx `.conf` file

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.local;

  root "/var/www/html";
  index index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ~ \.html$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```