# php code inside html files not executed

Tags: php, html

On my server, I am using nginx with php5-fpm (not Apache).

All the HTML, JavaScript and php code in my index.php file runs fine. But if I rename the file to index.html, the embedded php code doesn't execute. (All the HTML and JavaScript code continue to work fine.)

Several answers recommend adding the line

`AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm`

to the `.htaccess` file, but after downloading, installing and configuring nginx and php5-fpm, there was no `.htaccess` file on my server. So I created one, pasted the above line and placed the file in the website's root directory along with `index.html`. I restarted nginx, but the php code still does not work. (To be absolutely sure, I simply changed the file extension from html to php and everything is perfect.)

When I use firebug on the rendered page in my browser, the php tag and code don't appear to be there.

Comment: What do you mean by " When I use firebug on the rendered page in my browser, the php tag and code don't appear to be there."?

Comment: Anything helpful here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644783/html-files-as-php-in-nginx

Comment: `.htaccess` files are an apache-only feature and nginx will never support such a feature. You need to add something like that to the vHost config.

Comment: http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-nginx-html-files-as-php-1817.html

Comment: I don't know what you mean by vHost and there is no such file on my server.  If I have to create one, I have no idea where to put it.

Comment: There appear to be no virtual host configuration files on my server.  There is also no /etc/nginx/conf.d folder and there appear to be no virtual host configuration files anywhere.  Do I have to create these and does someone have a good example for what they should contain?

Answer (score 1):

OK, finally found the solution.  Someone had posted that I needed to change the location statement in my configuration file to

```
location ~ \.(php|html)$ {
```

so that both php and html files would be run through fastcgi.  When I tried this, I got an "access denied" error.  The problem there was that by default, nginx is restricted to running only php files through fastcgi.  This can be changed by uncommenting the line near the bottom of:

`/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

that reads

```
;security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5
```

and adding .html so that it now reads

```
security.limit_extensions = .php .html
```

when I reloaded and restarted nginx, voila! It works perfect.

While these two changes allow ngnix to process php code inside html files,  the other side of the story is that this increases the vulnerability of your server to malicious php code embedded in html files that might get uploaded to it.  The recommendation that I received was to give all your files with php code in them the .php extension.

Comment: I don't know why the backslash didn't show up in the location statement in front of \.(php|html) in my answer, but it has to be there for the code to work.  I am unfamiliar with the editing features and quirks on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, just spent hours on this!!! The final solution is correct from above.

It appears that if "/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf" has the full original line:security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5
you can not just ADD .html .js

The line reads:security.limit_extensions = .php .html
and now it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

Edit your conf file:

```
location ~ \.htm$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.htm;
            include        fastcgi.conf;
  }
```

Comment: Didn't realize at first. Thanks for informing anyway. @CharlotteDunois

Comment: Not sure what happened.  There was no block like the one you posted.  I changed the .php$ to .htm$ in the php location block and nothing happened.  I added a new block exactly as you posted and got an access denied message.

Comment: OK, I made a goofy mistake and forgot to put $ after .htm.  Having fixed that mistake and retried, webpage returned but no php input.

Comment: Also location ~ \.(php|html|htm)$ { results in access denied message.

Comment: It would be great if you posted the error message along with your edits in conf @user309572